# ¿como agregar lo escrito en input a un array?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let arrayPaises= ['eeuu', 'colombia', 'noruega', 'islandia', 'peru']

arrayPaises.map((e, key)=>{
   jQuery('ul').append('<li>'+e+'</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="pincipal"></ul>
<input type="text" id="contenido">
<button id="insertar()">insertar</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para llenar tu `array` y seguir alimentando la lista de países podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
let arrayPaises= ['eeuu', 'colombia', 'noruega', 'islandia', 'peru']

function llenarLista(){
  $('ul').html('');
  
  arrayPaises.map((e, key)=>{
   $('ul').append('<li>'+e+'</li>');
  });
}

$("#insertar").click(function(){
  let valor = $("#contenido").val();
  
  arrayPaises.push(valor);
  
  llenarLista();
  
  $("#contenido").val('');
})

llenarLista();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="pincipal"></ul>
<input type="text" id="contenido">
<button id="insertar">insertar</button>
```

Con el método `.push()` añadimos valores al array y ejecutamos una función que nos recorra esos valores y los imprima en el `<ul>`.

Si tienes dudas con gusto las responderé.

Comment: como?pudes poner el codigo??

Comment: @CamiloVasquez el [método `.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push) no es de jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Tu error principal es que estás intentando llamar a una función asignándosela al botón como un `id`. Deberías de usar el atributo `onclick` en su defecto.

Por otro lado, el cuerpo de tu función debería ser con la forma:

```
function nombreFuncion(){
    //Código
}
```

Una vez tengas hecha la función puedes hacer referencia al `input` mediante la función `document.getElementById` (método de Javascript) o `$("#id")` (método de JQuery) y obtener su valor haciendo referencia al atributo `value` o la función `val()` respectivamente.

Por último, asignar ese nuevo valor a tu lista.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

#### Usando Javascript

```js
let arrayPaises= ['eeuu', 'colombia', 'noruega', 'islandia', 'peru']

arrayPaises.map((e, key)=>{
   $('ul').append('<li>'+e+'</li>');
});

function insertar(){
  var contenido = document.getElementById("contenido").value;
  $('ul').append('<li>'+contenido+'</li>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="pincipal"></ul>
<input type="text" id="contenido">
<button onclick="insertar()">insertar</button>
```

#### Usando JQuery

```js
let arrayPaises= ['eeuu', 'colombia', 'noruega', 'islandia', 'peru']

arrayPaises.map((e, key)=>{
   $('ul').append('<li>'+e+'</li>');
});

function insertar(){
  var contenido = $("#contenido").val();
  $('ul').append('<li>'+contenido+'</li>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="pincipal"></ul>
<input type="text" id="contenido">
<button onclick="insertar()">insertar</button>
```

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Realmente lo he hecho con Javascript ya que es la única etiqueta que está presente en la pregunta. De todas maneras, ahora completo con la versión en JQuery.

Comment: para que sirve document.getElementById??

Comment: @steven Sirve para hacer referencia a un elemento mediante su ID. Sería lo mismo que `$("#ID")`

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Sí, yo también he visto las etiquetas y sabía perfectamente que era Jquery. Ahora pongo ambos ejemplos para que quede más completa la respuesta.

Comment: gracias a los dos,enserio me han ayudado bastante